# How to test for a blank line using cin

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, cstring, cin

Below is the code for a function i'm using to input student data into an array of student structures. I want the loop to terminate when i has reached the limit (n) which is fine OR, and this is what i'm having trouble with, when a blank line is typed for a student name? Does anybody have any suggestions? The current method i'm using doesn't work (the if statement below ' cin.getline(pa[i].fullname, SLEN - 1); ')

```
int getinfo(student pa[], int n)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter student details:\n\n";

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student " << (i + 1) << ": \n";
        cout << "  > Full name: ";
        cin.getline(pa[i].fullname, SLEN - 1);
        if (pa[i].fullname == NULL)
            continue;
        cout << "  > Hobby: ";
        cin.getline(pa[i].hobby, SLEN - 1);
        cout << "  > OOP Level: ";
        cin >> pa[i].ooplevel;;
        cin.get();

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better with `string` and with an atomic loop:

```
std::string name, hobby, oop;

std::cout << "Name: ";
if (!(std::getline(std::cin, name)) { break; }

std::cout << "Hobby: ";
if (!(std::getline(std::cin, hobby)) { break; }

std::cout << "OOP: ";
if (!(std::getline(std::cin, oop)) { break; }

// if we got here, everything succeeded.
pa[i].name = name; pa[i].hobby = hobby; pa[i].oop = oop;

// or better, pass a `std::vector<student> &`:
pa.push_back(student(name, hobby, oop));
```

Comment: i have to use the student structure unaltered which is:

const int SLEN = 30;

struct student
{
 char fullname[SLEN];
 char hobby[SLEN];
 int ooplevel; // levels 1-9   1 = beginner, 9 = expert 
};

Comment: You "have to"? What's going on? Is this homework and you didn't tag the question as such?

Comment: It wasn't homework, it was practise using structures.

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` reads an empty string for an empty line. Note that you shall **always** check if you input was successful. Personally I would use `std::string` as well.

Comment: what code would i use to break the loop when an empty string is read then?

Comment: I have changed my in statement to:

    if (pa[i].fullname[0] == '\0')
        break;

And it now breaks if nothing is entered for the student name

Feel like this very simple question doesn't deserve a place on the web! Sorry guys and thanks for your help.